# How to know whether there are pipelines input to a perl program

Tags: perl, input, pipeline

I can use `<>` to loop there the pipeline input to a perl program. However how can I decide whether there are pipelined input, if there is no pipelined input I will use environment variable to load a file. I am trying to use:

```
my @lines = (<>);
if ($#lines == -1) {
    use setenv;
    open FILE, "$ENV{'ART_FILE_LIST'}" or die $!;
    @lines = <FILE>;
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work, because the program will waiting at the first line

Comment: That `use setenv` does nothing.

Comment: use setenv is my custom module to setup environment variables including ART_FILE_LIST. It's not relevant to the question indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use 5.010_000;

use utf8;
use strict;
use autodie;
use warnings qw<  FATAL all  >;
use open     qw< :std  :utf8 >;

END {
   close(STDOUT) 
       || die "can't close stdout: $!";
}


if (@ARGV == 0 && -t STDIN) {
    # NB: This is magic open, so the envariable
    #     could hold a pipe, like 'cat -n /some/file |'
    @ARGV = $ENV{ART_FILE_LIST} 
          || die q(need $ART_FILE_LIST envariable set);
}

while (<>) {
    # blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: it works. thx. Just one typo: "use open qr< :std :utf8>" should be "use open qw< :std :utf8>"

Comment: @user391227, glad it worked. The `qr//` thing must be “muscle memory”: I’ve been typing lots more `qr`’s than `qw`’s lately. That’s at least the second time I’ve done that in as many days.  But I’ve typed 100 `qr`’s a day. Sorry!

Comment: BTW, could you please let me know what does END {} block do?

Comment: user391227: The `END{}` delares an “at-exit” handler, code to run when the program is about to exit.  BTW, if you edit your profile, you can have a real user name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -t operator to see if you are a terminal, i.e., not a pipeline:

```
if (-t STDIN) { print "Terminal\n" } 
        else { print "Not a terminal\n" }
```

Comment: Wouldn't checking `-t STDIN` be better? (Note: I'm not a perl expert) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518992

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Getopt::Long`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong)

```
perl -Mylib -e 'Mylib::do_stuff' --i_am_pipe_lined
```

One of the things about UNIX pipelines is that they achieve their usefulness by not caring what's before them or after them. They just have a job to do and they do it. They do one thing, simply, but they all have switches to do their simple job with a little more customization.

Comment: @tchrist: It's kind of like `oose.pm`. I wrote `-MMylib` for a generic mod, and I just preferred the `oose` look. Mylib would contains the definition for `do_stuff`. For a number of tasks that I develop for the commandline, I prefer developing *in* a module that expects to be called in different circumstances and then using some `-e` expression to kick it off rather than writing a one off script. I think it makes it more customizable per use than a script. YMMV

Comment: @tchrist: I find it's easier to make building blocks and some things that look a lot simpler on a command line--for example `-e 'process pipelined => 1'` by approaching it from the start with a building-block design.

Comment: @Axeman: I never think that way. I am very program-oriented. `main(argc, argv)` is indelibly burned into my wetware. It’s hard for me to think in a completely module-centric way, which means I end up writing wrappers and such. That said, I almost always write programs, not modules. Are you a Java programmer by chance?

Comment: @tchrist: Been one. But I actually picked both languages up at about the same time. I much prefer writing 5 lines of Perl to writing 30 lines of Java to give it a chance to know what I mean. Of course, I think the main thing was that I worked in a system where there was a lot of lock-down on system ideas. But our scheduling system could create jobs with a command line, so I saved a lot of development time creating command line suite of utilities which only received the "What are you doing?" treatment after I had built up a sizable suite of tools.